# Проверка заполнения всех полей формы

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-form

Есть большая форма, содержащая большое количество:

```
<input type="text" id="AxBy" name="AxBy" class="AB-input">
```

В разных ситуациях количество таких полей разное, но всегда > 100. Есть ли какой-либо простой способ проверить сразу все поля на факт заполнения используя JavaScript или jQuery не прибегая к циклам и не перебирая каждый элемент по отдельности? Вариант минимум - получить ответ: все поля заполнены/есть незаполненные поля, вариант максимум - получить ответ: все поля заполнены корректными целочисленными значениям/есть некорректные данные (не все значения целочисленные)/ не все поля заполнены.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать встроенные средства проверки полей формы:

- обязательное поле (required);
- для проверки целочисленных цифровых    значений (pattern). \d+ только
  одна или более цифра.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const formSubmit = document.querySelector('button');

form.addEventListener('change', changeFormHandler);

function changeFormHandler() {
  console.log(form.checkValidity());
  if (form.checkValidity()) {
    formSubmit.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input
    name="field1"
    pattern="\d+"
    required
  >
  <input
    name="field2"
    pattern="\d+"
    required
  >
  <button
    disabled
  >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var empties = $("form").find('input:text').filter(function() { 
  // добавьте здесь дополнительные проверки на целочисленность и т.п.
  return $(this).val() == ""; 
});

if (empties.length > 0) {
  console.log("has empty inputs");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри как я сделал для своей формы, каждое поле проверяю.
Плюсы: Могу управлять каждым полем, на каждое поле могу написать свой валидатор.

```
$("form[name='name_form']").submit(function(event, i) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var curform = $(this);
    var goodform =  true;
    var name = $(this).attr("name");

    curform.find('.required').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr("name"))
        //debugger;
        switch($(this).attr("name")) {
            case "phone":
                if( $(this).val().length != 18) {
                    goodform = false;
                }

            case "first_name":
                if( $(this).val().length < 0) {
                   goodform = false;
                }
        }
    });
    if (goodform) {
       alert("Успех")

    }
})
```